# How to know if duplicate library is Module or group?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting duplicate library error on Gradle, One of the `aar` file i have added in my project has come up with the `http-client-library` library.

[image]

Now i need to remove this library from this `SDK library` file, because some other library is also using it.

I have tried following.

```
 compile(name: 'SDK-app-1.0.0', ext: 'aar'){
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
```

but it does not effect it, I can still see `httpclient` library in the sub module of `SDK-app` library.

I am unable to understand what should i need to add here? Is it a Module or library, or should i set `transitive=true` to remove this library from the `aar` file.

and When i try to add this library in my project

> Duplicate zip entry
>   [android-async-http-1.4.9.jar:com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient$1.class])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### If you know the `compile` statement

The easiest way of figuring this thing out is getting the `compile` statement you would usually add the dependency to your project.

Then you can take it apart to get the `group` and the `module`. Like so:

1. Identify first colon
2. Identify second colon
3. Everything from the beginning to the first colon is `group`
4. Everything between first and second colon is `module`

[image: taking apart compile statement]

Excluding the dependency would be as easy as:

```
compile 'some.imaginary:library:4.8.15', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.dagger', module: 'dagger'
}
```

---

### If you don't know the `compile` statement

Things get a bit more complicated (but not much) if you don't have your `compile` statement. You can either:

1. Try to figure out the `module` and the `group` looking for the artifact online. For example in the [Maven repository search engine](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-android/4.3.5.1). If you look at the Maven dependency you can see the `groupId` tag which represents your `group` and the `artifactId` tag which represents your `module`.

   [image: maven dependency]
2. Or you can use gradle locally:

   1. Open `Terminal` pane in your Android Studio:

   [image: terminal]

   2. Type in: `./gradlew androidDependencies`
   3. Find the row that relates to the library you're trying to exclude and split it the same way I did in the first example:

   [image: androidDependencies]

Comment: Thank you for such an awesome explanation !! :)

Comment: Glad I could help! :)